# Short story about a person living alone in a "pod"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story that I read many years ago (15? probably more...). It might actually be an amateur short story.

I remember the protagonist waking up inside some very small "cell" or "pod". I think he interacted with somebody on a computer inside said cell, but this might just be me mixing with other stories.

What I really remember is the end, where he manages to get out of said cell to find out he's actually alone on some warehouse, and he finds out he did something horrible and that he erased his own memory, so he goes back inside.